# How to execute an individual JUnit test from its corresponding test resources

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit

For each of the class, we have a corresponding test class and test resource. For example, for class `Example.java` under `src/main/java`, we have test class `TestExample.java` under `src/test/java` and resource directory called `Example` under `src/test/resources`.

I can run all test cases directly from test resources if they share the same directory structure. I can execute on test resource directory under `src/test/resources` and IntelliJ will automatically launch all test classes under the same directory path under `src/test/java`. My question is, how could I make IntelliJ just run one test class on that test directory instead of all the other test classes? If I try to execute on the specific class name, it says `0 test classes found in package`, but I can just go to the parent directory and execute, which will execute all the classes within that directory. Is there any way I can execute a single test class within a directory through test resource?

Comment: best would be if you would share your code on github, so people can run it locally and try to supply you with help

Comment: Do you have any actual tests in the ExampleTest.java? Please add code to your question

Comment: A screenshot of your project structure would also help

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do and why. You can tell IntelliJ which tests you want to run and the test will then pick up whatever resources it is programmed to use (e.g. using `getClass().getResourceAsStream()`). But you sound like you want to point at resources instead? Why?

Comment: @flup Convenience. We have dozens of test classes and corresponding dozens of test resources for each one of the test class. We have abstracted away the testing harness, so that tester can focus on inputs and the expected output. Thus, it would be convenient if the tester can execute testing directly from the test resources since the test class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is likely several ways to do what you want, this is one way:

You need to tell IntelliJ which test you want to run, one way to do that is to click the "Tests" tab to switch the project view to show the tests. You may prefer the "Packages" tab if you work with the resources, it will show a package-centric view grouping your tests and test resources in the same structure.

[image: The tests tab]

After that, locate the test, right-click and select "run" from the popup menu.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you used an IntelliJ tag on this question, I'm assuming you are using Maven as the lifecycle framework of you project.
Under this assumption, I'd suggest you use the surefire plugin found [here](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit.html)

One of the many nice features surefire has is the ability to group tests and run specific test groups only (copied from the content of the link above):

***Using JUnit Categories***
JUnit 4.8 introduced the notion of Categories. You can use JUnit categories by using the groups parameter. As long as the JUnit version in the project is 4.8 or higher, the presence of the "groups" parameter will automatically make Surefire select the junit47 provider, which supports groups.

```
<plugins>
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.11</version>
  <configuration>
    <groups>com.mycompany.SlowTests</groups>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

This will execute only those tests annotated with the @Category(com.mycompany.SlowTests.class) annotation and those tests annotated with @Category(com.mycompany.SlowerTests.class) if class/interface SlowerTests is subclass of SlowTests:

```
public interface SlowTests{}
public interface SlowerTests extends SlowTests{}
public class AppTest {
  @Test
  @Category(com.mycompany.SlowTests.class)
  public void testSlow() {
    System.out.println("slow");
  }

  @Test
  @Category(com.mycompany.SlowerTests.class)
  public void testSlower() {
    System.out.println("slower");
  }

  @Test
  @Category(com.cmycompany.FastTests.class)
  public void testSlow() {
    System.out.println("fast");
  }
}
```

**The @Category annotation can also be applied at class-level.**

Comment: Man, that was my first thought when I saw the question.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your test directory is marked as "test root",

see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000741910--0-test-classes-found-in-package-after-upgrading-to-2017-3

Answer (score 0):

[image: IntelliJ run single test method]

After you open the test class in IntelliJ, you should see a green circle with a small triangle on bottom. It's present on left hand side where the line numbers appear on the editor. If you click on it you should be able to kick off tests for that class only. You can also kick off individual tests within a test class.